# elixir mock inner function url request

Tags: testing, mocking, elixir

How could I mock a specific api call similar to how python requests-mock works:

```
with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    m.get('http://test.com', text='data')
    requests.get('http://test.com').text
```

In this example every call to `http://test.com` inside the with statement will be mocked

So in elixir, for example, I have this:

```
defmodule API do

  # makes a call to an external API I dont want to test
  def make_call do
    ...
  end
end

defmodule Item do

  alias API

  # function I actually want to test
  def build_request do
    API.make_call
    # stuff I want to test
  end

end
```

So let's say I want to test `build_request` mocking `make_call`

I tried this package https://github.com/jjh42/mock but what this package does is to override whole API module with for example a mock for `make_call` method but you also lose all the other functions of the API module and I dont want that.

How could I mock that call?

Here in another example I saw https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/mocking-api-s-with-elixir

```
# mocking a github api call directly
@github_api.make_request(:get, "/users/#{username}")
```

But it's the same issue, it mocks the request straight in the test, my issue is when the mock needs to be done in an **inner** function not straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is your friend:

```
def build_request(caller \\ API) do
  caller.make_call
  # stuff I want to test
end
```

And in tests you supply a parameter to the call to `build_request`:

```
build_request(TestAPI)
```

For the details please refer to this [brilliant writing](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/) by José Valim.

Comment: That's fine for when you can use DI, but what if you're relying on side effect that results from a BIF (the setup found in the start/2 function of an OTP application entry point would be a good example)?

Comment: @Charlie I am not sure I follow. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: `def start(_type, _args) do 
start_link([], [strategy: :one_for_one, name: :root]) 
end`

I mean, perhaps I'm trying to do the wrong this testing this, and indeed, I guess I could run the function, and just test for the presence of the named processes in the dependency tree. But if I did want to spy on start_link/2, what are my options?

Comment: I doubt I understand the purpose of testing `def foo(), do: bar()` does indeed call `bar()` (if it does not, _nothing_ works,) but the dependency injection is still your best friend: declare a dedicated clause for your tests `def start(_type, mock: true), do: Test.start_link())` and test whatever you want there.